# Enable developer mode with --dev=all?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I tried to start Odoo 11 directly in developer mode by using the arg `--dev=all` without having to pass by `Settings` then `Activate the developer mode` but it doesn't works. I've also a Warning about the Watchdog module which is missing but I can't find it in the module list. Does `--dev=all` is used for something else?

Comment: And one more info: There are some browser plugins, which integrate a button into your browser to toggle the client developer mode of Odoo. [For example for the chrome browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/odoo-debug/hmdmhilocobgohohpdpolmibjklfgkbi)

Comment: You must `pip install watchdog` to get rid of that warning, and also get the super handy feature of auto-reloading .py files while developing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this if you notice what happen when you activate developer mode it's just adding this word to the url.      `debug=`.
So just save a favorite link i don't remember exactly but it should be something like this.

```
  server_ip:8069/web?debug=
```

Answer (score 9):

The command-line parameter/option `--dev=all` is used for development to load records/data (Odoo is very data-driven) like views, templates or reports directly from code instead from database. That has one big advantage: you don't have to update apps to checkout changes in that part of code (mostly .xml files). A disadvantage: translations are not working as expected.

Comment: Very informative thank you. This will save me a lot of time i think by doing this we don't have to restard odoo server and upgrade the module when we change just xml files.

Comment: i tried this but it's not working is there anything I need to do rather than installing whatchdog or it's not working because i'm using windows

Comment: Sorry, i've never used windows for odoo developement. Which odoo version do you develop for?

Comment: I used it in 10 version for a pdf report but when i change the file even after 2 minute nothing changes.

Comment: You shouldn't have to wait any timespan, because the xml is loaded from file in that mode. But as i said, i don't have experience with odoo developement on windows.

Answer (score 1):

as @CZoellner sad `--dev=all` is used for developement mode to lead views and templates directly  from files instead of database ,
to start debug mode from cli  you can pass this `--log-level=debug`